# Getting total for Invoiced Paid and the amount owing for each client

Tags: mysql

I have tried many of the scripts that I found here but none did what I required.

I have 3 tables: `clients`, `invoiced` and `payments`.

I would like to:

- sum all invoices per client within a date range
- sum all payments for clients with in the date range then subtract payments from invoiced to show amount outstanding.

I need to add the date range and get the total if not zero.

So far my query is

```
select id,
   (select sum(Total) from invoiced  where invoiced.ClientId = clients.Id) AS Invoiced,
   (select sum(Amount) from payments  where payments.ClientId = clients.Id) AS Paid
FROM clients
```

Comment: show DB schema as well, not clear date range will be applied on which date field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the non existing relation between the invoice and the payments.
This makes it a bit "dirtier" ;)

Try this:

```
select p.id, sum(i.total), sum(p.amount), sum(i.total) - sum(p.amount) as outstanding
from 
(
select c.id, coalesce(pay.amount,0) as amount
from 
  (select ClientId, Sum(Amount) amount from payments group by ClientId) as pay 
  right join clients c on c.id = pay.ClientId
) p
left join
(
select c.id, inv.total
from 
  (select ClientId, Sum(Total) total from invoiced group by ClientId) as inv
  left join clients c on c.id = inv.ClientId
) i
on p.id = i.id
group by id
having sum(i.total) <> sum(p.amount)
;
```

Updated [**Sqlfiddle with results here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7305/1)

Comment: There is no third column that shows the invoiced - the paid. How would you suggest creating a relationship between a table that contains records reflecting adhoc work done in a month and adhoc payments done for that work?

Comment: normally you do a payment using an invoice (invoice number), right?... but the paid amount must not be the same as what is specified in the invoice, some pay less than what is invoiced. Anyway, I did try the sqlfiddle and the results should be what David asks for.

Comment: Thank you it works. If I only wanted to show non zero balances? Regarding your relation ship comment. The invoiced table is more accuratly a jobs table. It is all the work done before the invoice is issued. But because clients paye per job they get multiple invoices in a month, they should settle per invoice but some only pay at end of month.

Comment: Great that it helped, you can always put in a where clause to filter out zeroes, And check the sqlfiddle I added a date column so you can put a where date is between startdate and endate. Good luck!

Comment: where would I put the where? Sorry I am a complete SQL novice

Comment: You dont want to show rows where outstanding is zero? right?

Comment: I did a bit of testing and it looks as if there is an error here. I found a person who has an amount in the invoiced table but has no records in the payments table. It shows nothing for this client. These are the very ones I need to see. They have not paid yet

Comment: If you want to remove zero outstanding rows, use the `having` after groupby. See the edit. Check also your data, and put it in sqlfiddle to share if you have any strange results.

Comment: I deleted this line from your sqlfiddle insert into payments values( 3, 1, '2015-01-01' ); And see the same error. It does not show that Carl owes 10

Comment: Ok, you have such situations too. then you  need a right join instead of the left join. I will update the query in 1 min.